# angularjs filter object property without ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array of objects and I need to return object containing specific property.

```
$scope.foobar = [
    {"id": 15, "name": "bar1"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "bar2"},
    {"id": 215, "name": "bar3"},
    {"id": 7415, "name": "bar4"}
];
```

I need to assign a new variable with the object where `id` is `25`. The following does not work:

```
<div ng-init="item = foobar | filter: { id: 25 }">...</div>
```

How can I use angular filter without `ng-repeat` to select the subset of items from array and return it as a new array.

Comment: why do you use ng-init??? don't you wanna use ng-repeat???

Comment: I need to assign variable only with one of the objects within that array, I don't need to output anything in the view. I can create filter with  `forEach` loop, but I wonder if there's a built-in way to select the subset of items from array in angular.

Comment: ok try `<div ng-repeat="foo in foobar | filter:{id:25}">`

Comment: it shows just the filtered object !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view doesn't need it, don't put it in the template. If you don't want to write your own filtering function and use angular filterFilter (some of the naming fun with angular :)), inject it into your controller and set your variable there.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', function ($scope, filterFilter) {

  $scope.foobar = [
    {"id": 15, "name": "bar1"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "bar2"},
    {"id": 215, "name": "bar3"},
    {"id": 7415, "name": "bar4"}
  ];
  
  // use the filter Filter to set your var
  $scope.item = filterFilter($scope.foobar, {id: 25});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  {{item}}  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is too old to answer, but may be it will help other.

```
<span ng-bind="(foobar | filter : {id : 25 } : true)[0].name"></span>
```

you can also use `$scope` variable instead of 25

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that extracts the correct data:

```
$scope.getFoo = function(id){
  for(var i = 0; i< foobar.length;++i)
    if(foobar[i].id === id)
      return foobar[i];
};

$scope.foobar = [
    {"id": 15, "name": "bar1"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "bar2"},
    {"id": 215, "name": "bar3"},
    {"id": 7415, "name": "bar4"}
];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="item = getFoo(25)">...</div>
```